# Cycle Visual Studio intellisense context menu using tab

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2015, hotkeys

Is it possible to configure Visual Studio to cycle the intellisense context menu using <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> (and <kbd>Enter</kbd> for selecting) while still being able to insert tabs using <kbd>Tab</kbd>?

Binding (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+)<kbd>Tab</kbd> to `Edit.LineDown`/`Edit.LineUp` enables the cycle behavior but removes the `Edit.InsertTab` behavior.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out?